# Same XAML but different code behind for user controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 user controls in WPF which have the same layout (a few buttons and a listview) but the code in behind is different because the listviews list collections of different classes.

Is it possible to somehow use the same XAML for the three usercontrols? Because right now, if I make a change to the layout of one XAML I have to do it for the other two manually.

Thanks

Comment: Do the classes share a common base type? Do the 3 lists display the same data?

Comment: They all inherit UserControl and the lists display different data.

Comment: I meant the collection types, do they share a common base type? Also, what reuse are you expecting if all of the lists display different data (and presumably have different layouts?)

Comment: All of them are LINQ to SQL generated classes. I want to reuse the layout (XAML) of the user control.

Answer (score 3):

That's  perfect scenario for [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Create a single `UserControl` or `View`

Create three different backend classes which will act as `ViewModel`

For each instance of `UserControl` use different `ViewModel` as `DataContext`

Comment: +1 for mentioning MVVM, looks like OP is not aware of this great pattern

Answer (score 1):

1) Extract common XAML into the separate XAML file and then in target control's use it as DataTemplate:

```xml
    <!-- 1. CommonView.xaml would contains common XAML -->

    <!-- 2. Below is XAML of the any of three control -->    
    <UserControl>
        <!-- In three controls use shared XAML as data template -->
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="sharedTemplate">
                <views:CommonView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>

        <MyControl>
           <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource sharedTemplate}" />
        </MyControl>
    </UserControl>
```

2) Bind each of the control to a separate ViewModel